# Find empty, non-ignored directories

Tags: git

I want to add a `.gitkeep` file to all the empty directories in my repo, but **not** to ignored directories. I can already find empty directories with:

```
$ find . -type d -empty
```

But how can I tell which ones are ignored? They could be directly ignored, or a child of an ignored directory ... Is there a way to get this information from `git` directly? Something like:

```
$ find . -type d -empty | git classify --stdin

ignored     : xxx
non-ignored : yyy
```

Would be great.

Comment: Couldn't you simply add a `.gitkeep` to **all** directories, if you add a file into an ignored folder it will be ignored anyway.

Comment: Sure, but that does not seem very clean

Comment: I don't think it would be very clean to add `.gitkeep` files at all since they are not a feature of git from the first place. Better to add something like a `README` to those directories which have a short text explaining their purpose.

Comment: That is a matter of taste. I **do not** like READMEs whose only purpose is to force a directory structure into git. But the name of the file is besides the point: I want to do this automatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) for this task.

---

Let's assume you have a repository with the following structure:

```
foo/a.tmp
foo/b
bar/test/
baz/
```

And this `.gitignore`:

```
foo/*.tmp
bar/
```

If you now pass the output of `find . -type d -empty` to `git check-ignore`, you would recieve the following output:

```
$ find . -type d -empty | git check-ignore --stdin
./bar/test
```

As you can see `git check-ignore` returns the folders which are matched by your `.gitignore`. For a more detailed output, you can use the `-n` (`--non-matching`) option, which needs to be combined with `-v` (`--verbose`).

```
$ find . -type d -empty | git check-ignore --stdin -nv
::  ./.git/branches
::  ./.git/objects/info
::  ./.git/objects/pack
::  ./.git/refs/tags
.gitignore:1:bar/   ./bar/test
::  ./baz
```

To exclude the `.git` folder from your search you can provide further parameters to `find` ([documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)).

```
$ find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" | git check-ignore --stdin -nv
.gitignore:1:bar/   ./bar/test
::  ./baz
```

From here on you can simply `grep` the folders which are not matched by your `.gitignore` and remove the leading `::`:

```
$ find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" | git check-ignore --stdin -nv | grep '::' | sed -E 's/::[[:space:]]*//'
./baz
```